# Laravel 5 Route binding and Hashid

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, hashids

I am using Hashid to hide the id of a resource in Laravel 5.

Here is the route bind in the routes file:

```
Route::bind('schedule', function($value, $route)
{
    $hashids = new Hashids\Hashids(env('APP_KEY'),8);
    if( isset($hashids->decode($value)[0]) )
    {
        $id = $hashids->decode($value)[0];
        return App\Schedule::findOrFail($id);
    }
    App::abort(404);
});
```

And in the model:

```
public function getRouteKey()
{
    $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids(env('APP_KEY'),8);
    return $hashids->encode($this->getKey());
}
```

Now this works fine the resource displays perfectly and the ID is hashed.
BUT when I go to my create route, it 404's -  if I remove App::abort(404) the create route goes to the resource 'show' view without any data...

Here is the Create route:

```
Route::get('schedules/create', [
  'uses' => 'SchedulesController@create',
  'as' => 'schedules.create'
]);
```

The Show route:

```
Route::get('schedules/{schedule}', [
  'uses' => 'Schedules Controller@show',
  'as' => 'schedules.show'
]);
```

I am also binding the model to the route:

```
Route::model('schedule', 'App\Schedule');
```

Any ideas why my create view is not showing correctly? The index view displays fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to solve this, I had to rearrange my crud routes.

Create needed to come before the Show route...

Answer (score 0):

There's a package that does exactly what you want to do: https://github.com/balping/laravel-hashslug

Also note, that it's not a good idea to use `APP_KEY` as salt because [it can be exposed](http://carnage.github.io/2015/08/cryptanalysis-of-hashids).

Using the above package all you need to do is add a trait and typehint in controller:

```php
class Post extends Model {
    use HasHashSlug;
}
```

```php
// routes/web.php
Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
```

```php
// app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php

public function show(Post $post){
  return view('post.show', compact('post'));
}
```